# Vue.js event emitting from child component to (grand)parent component using global eventbus

Tags: events, vue.js, vue-component

I want to use a global eventbus to emit events from a child up to a (grand)parent.

In **My main.js:** I make a global eventbus available to all components.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
const eventHub = new Vue()

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})

Vue.mixin({
  data: function () {
    return {
      eventHub: eventHub
    }
  }
})
```

Then, in my **Childcomponent.vue:** I emit an event to the eventbus on a click event

```
<template>
  <button @click="save">Save</button>
</template>

<script>
  let data = {
    columnName: '',
    order: 0
  }

  export default {
    ...
    name: 'init-column',
    methods: {
      save: function () {
        this.eventHub.$emit('newColumn', data)
      }
    }
    ...
  }
</script>
```

Then, in a **Parentcomponent.vue** I want to catch this event and do something with the data that the child had transmitted:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
      <column v-for="column in allData"></column>
      <init-column v-if="newColumn"></init-column>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import initColumn from './components/Init-column'

  let newColumn = false

  export default {
    ...
    name: 'project',
    ready: function () {
      this.eventHub.$on('newColumn', (event) => {
        console.log(event)
      })
    }
    ...
  }
</script>
```

I'm not sure where to put the `$on` listener, I saw examples where they put `$on` in the ready hook. The code above does nothing, however I get no error in the console.

Comment: Put the event hub in its own file and export it then import it in the other files to use the same instance. Or you can just use this.$root for all event emits/ons

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The ability to do this goes away with **Vue 3**. The RFC below mentions the motivation and links to some issues for further help.

https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0020-events-api-change.md

---

I don't think `data` is the right place for the event bus. I definitely wouldn't use a global mixin for it either.

What I've done in the past is have a simple `bus.js` file like:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
export default new Vue()
```

Then, in any component that needs the bus I just

```
import bus from './bus.js'
```

Then I normally do this to emit events.

```
bus.$emit('foo', whatever)
```

and this to catch them

```
created () {
  bus.$on('foo', this.someMethod)
}
```

I prefer to do it in created since that's the earliest step in the lifecycle you can do this.

Also, this issue on github has some very nice examples: https://github.com/vuejs/vuejs.org/pull/435

Comment: I got the mixin approach from the official [migration guide](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#dispatch-and-broadcast-replaced) I'm a beginner with vue.js. How else would you transfer data up from a child, other than emitting event? I'll check your github link.

Comment: It's normally recommend to use Vuex but for a smaller project that might be overkill.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am trying to avoid. It is a relatively simple project. I'm trying to keep it that way.

Comment: Support for this kind of events has been removed https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0020-events-api-change.md

Comment: Thanks Eden. I'll mention this at the top of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `$on` listener in the created hook as specified in the docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication

You cannot use `ready` hook in Vue 2.0. `ready` hook was originally available in Vue 1.x, but now deprecated.

Comment: when using in the created hook, I get: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$on' of undefined`

Comment: If so, then your `this.eventHub` is undefined within that component. The best method is to follow the example from @BillCriswell in his answer, where the `bus` is defined in `bus.js` and imported into any component where it is required.

Comment: But it should be available, right? Well, according to this [guide](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#dispatch-and-broadcast-replaced). If I `console.log(this)` at the `$emit` event I can see `eventHub` in the vue instance. However, at `$on`, I don't. I'll try @BillCriswell -s answer as soon as I can.

Comment: In that guide, eventHub is defined as a global variable, and is not part of the component. Also in your case, eventHub is only available in main.js, not in component files. You should also be able to find if it is available in the components using [vue-devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools)

Comment: Support for this kind of events has been removed

Answer (score 0):

I got the desired effect with a custom event: `@newColumn="event"`

```
<init-column @newColumn="event" v-if="newColumn"></init-column>
...
methods: { event: function(e) { console.log(e) }
```

So whenever I `$emit` from the child it does call the event method.

This works well, but for some strange reason the listener `$on` does not. Maybe I am missing something with the `$on` method.